# Как заставить gettext работать с русским языком в Python?

Tags: python, gettext

Всем доброго дня!
Пытаюсь выполнить перевод для CLI Python 3 программы с русского языка на английский с помощью gettext. Большинство строк в коде либо на русском, либо русский + английский. Файл исходного кода имеет кодировку `UTF-8`. Импортировал модуль, разметил строки, но когда пытаюсь сгенерировать файл `.pot` возникает ошибка с указанием на кодировку `cp1552`. Ниже команда, которую использую для генерации .pot и текст получаемой ошибки:

```
python pygettext.py -d base -o base.pot C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\test\main.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py", line 680, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py", line 673, in main
    eater.write(fp)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py", line 514, in write
    print('msgid', normalize(k, encoding), file=fp)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной ошибкой буду рад получить совет/краткое объяснение для её устранения.

Пример кода где возникает описанная проблема:

```
import gettext

_ = gettext.gettext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(_("тест"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка с кодировкой возникает при переименовании `pot` файла. Если просто извлечь все строки с помощью опции `-a, --extract-all` в файл с именем по умолчанию `messages.pot`, то все ок:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\ф\PycharmProjects\imagerec>  python C:\Users\ф\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py --extract-all 
ppp.py
```

Файл **messages.pot**

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR ORGANIZATION
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2024-02-18 23:51+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=cp1251\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: pygettext.py 1.5\n"


#: ppp.py:7
msgid "тест"
msgstr ""
```

Почему кодировка файла изменяется при переименовании я не знаю. Я не понял, почему вы используете две синонимичные, почти, опции  `-d` и `-o`  [читайте](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/pygettext.1.html), но применение любой из них вызывает ошибку кодировки. И еще видно, что файл `pot` получается в кодировке `cp1251` на винде.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что из-за этого открытия файла на запись без указания кодировки проблемы возникают: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53d5e67804227d541ed2f9e8efea8de5d70cb1ec/Tools/i18n/pygettext.py#L667C9-L667C40. В русскоязычной винде обычно в cp1251 пишет, возможно у автора вопроса винда не русскоязычная.

Comment: @insolor, да, винда англоязычная.

Comment: @Сергей-Кох, спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, не помогло, та же ошибка.

Comment: @JustAGuy это конечно не решение проблемы (скорее воркэраунд), но обычно делают основным языком английский, для него добавляют переводы. С сохранением текста только в латинице в кодировке cp1252 проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: @insolor Ваше предположение про влияние операционки было верно. Проверил в виртуалке с Ubuntu, получилось сгенерировать `.pot` файл, дело сдвинулось. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @JustAGuy, да на всех системах кроме винды при открытии текстового файла utf-8 используется по умолчанию, так что linux вполне подходящий вариант